# Is `<form target="_self">` acts like `location.replace()` that won't show in browser history?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hidden page immediately submit form looks like this

```html
<form
  target="_self"
  id="__ecpayForm"
  method="post"
  action="MY_API_DOMAIN"
></form>

<script>
  document.getElementById("__ecpayForm").submit();
</script>
```

My form will redirect the user to other page.

However, some user will press previous page button on their phone, and then the form submits again!

But some users don't have the issue.

Why is this happening?

How can I make sure when the user presses the previous button, they won't navigate to this hidden page?

Comment: this because some browser cache the previous page instead of loading it again, you can utilize cookie / localStorage to check whenever the user has already access the page

Comment: Thank you.
But my hidden form is in an iframe, iframe in safari can't use local storage.
And the page I'm redirecting isn't the same as the hidden page.

Comment: Does it have to be in an iframe? If seems like all you're using the form for is to ping a url. You can do that from javascript so there doesn't seem to be a reason for the form or the iframe and thus no reason for browser history to be a problem..

Comment: @Ouroborus yeah, I think I should eliminate that hidden page, thanks.